# How to route using list in Dropdown Angular 2

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-services

```
 <select class="form-control" id="category" required [(ngModel)]="model.category" name="category" #category="ngModel">
<option disabled>None</option>
<option> Add New </option>                                
<option *ngFor= "let i of data1"  [value]="i.id">{{i.category}}</option>                                    
 </select>
```

If i select Add New Option from dropdown it should Route to this path ['/pages/products/dashboard'] .

I already Tried by passed that link in `<option [routerLink]="['/EmployeeData']">` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the `onchange` event on the `select` element and have your routing logic in a function that triggers when the event comes from the `Add New` option.

[Example](https://codepen.io/hungryL/pen/NYBvax)